# What is Excel VBA "Template" Object?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to Debug an Excel Macro that has a "Template" object that I never used before. In the original code I was getting a subscript out of range error due to the following line of code:

```
ReDim VariableTemplateData(1 To VariableTemplateItems.Count, 1 To TemplateItem.PropertyCount)
```

The objects above are defined as:

```
Dim TemplateItem As Template
Dim VariableTemplateData() As String
Dim TemplateItems As Collection
```

The issue seems to be the TemplateItem, which is defined in the beginning of the script and again later, but before the redimension of the VariableTemplateData, as

```
Set TemplateItem = New Template
```

In an attempt to work on the code piece by piece, I copied a part of the script into a new excel file with just the starting code of

```
Dim SubAccountSheet As Worksheet
Dim TemplateSheet As Worksheet
Dim SubAccountDataRange As Range
Dim FXData As Variant
Dim SubAccountDict As Dictionary
Dim TemplateItems As Collection
Dim TemplateItem As Template
Dim KeyID As String
Dim VariableTemplateItems As Collection
Dim VariableTemplateData() As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
```

With just this code, I get a compile error "user-defined type not defined" from the "TemplateItem as Template" line. The previous file did not get this compile error. I ran to a similar issue in the past with Dictionary object where I had to check-off the Microsoft Scripting Runtime in the references but I can't find anything for "Template". Searching online yields a lot of templates and MS Word rather than anything helpful.

Any recommendations would be appreciated or direction to resources.

Comment: It is probably a custom class in the existing workbook.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I've never created custom classes before so wasn't aware that was a thing.